# non-PXE, non-DHCP cobbler media

Tags: cobbler

I have a single DHCP scope for building systems in one site, and another site which doesn't (at least yet) have infrastructure for building systems using cobbler.  Eventually I'd like to scale this all out, but for now I want to use the `cobbler buildiso` command to make CD media that contains a list of all systems/profiles.

I've set the `ip-address`, `network`, `gateway` fields for the system profile, in addition to all the other fields I use for PXE->DHCP setups.

It seems like I'm 80% there as the media is created, but the `syslinux.cfg` file doesn't seem to correctly populate ksdevice, ip, network, gateway.

My question is what is the *correct* way to get this configuration to work?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to set the relevant variables at the *profile* level, rather than at the system level.  Specifically you'll need to set `kernel_options`.  there you'll be able to set the network settings to be used during system build.

For example:

```
[root@rhnsat ~]# cobbler profile dumpvars --name=Default | grep "kernel_options :"
kernel_options : ksdevice=bootif lang=  kssendmac text
```